# Why my Thread run after Form creation?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delay

I have a project that main `Form` is created after my `Thread`.
But this code don't work correctly:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure doProc;
  end; { type }
.
.
.
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  thrd : TMyThread;
begin
  thrd := TMyThread.Create(True);
  thrd.Resume;

  // Following code will cause the `Form` to show the time delay is about 5 seconds...
end;
.
.
.

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

  doProc;
end;

procedure TMyThread.doProc;
var
  AForm : TForm;
begin
  AForm := TForm.Create(nil);
  AForm.Caption := 'Thread Form';
  AForm.Position := poScreenCenter;
  AForm.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
  AForm.Show;
end;
```

I don't want to use `Synchronize`.
Is there a way to run my `Thread` out of main `Form`?
I want to show a `Form` before the main `Form` begin to create while the main `Form` is shown.

Comment: If you want to create and show some form before the main one is created, do so. But not from a worker thread!

Comment: No, I don't want a splash screen.

Comment: My Thread Form do some process. I don't explain this in the code. Because my question is explicit.

Comment: @MartynA sorry for wrong explain

Comment: Are you sure it's a good suggestion?!

Comment: Not for me to say. Despite the answers to all your recent questions, you still don't seem to "get it" so far as VCL forms and threads are concerned, so reading around the subject might not do you any harm..

Comment: There is no answer my question

Comment: @MartynA I need a independent `Thread` than Windows to manage it outside my main `Form`.

Comment: @Mohammadreza There certainly is an answer to the question you asked. Please don't get confused between the answer to the question you asked, and the solution to the problem you face. You asked a question which we can answer. We cannot provide a solution to your problem because we do not know your problem. What we do here is answer questions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, my question is: I need a Thread that works independent, before `Form` be created. I want to do some codes in the `Thread`.

Comment: No. The question you asked is why your code doesn't work the way you expect. I answered that. As to how to run GUI in a thread I answered that too.

Comment: @Mohammadreza, if you want a threaded GUI, do not use the VCL. Peter Below made an example of a threaded splashscreen, not using any of the VCL. See [Threaded Splashscreen for Delphi](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/20139).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
unit AniThread;

interface 

uses 
  Classes, Windows, Controls, Graphics; 

type 
  TAnimationThread = class(TThread) 
  private 
    { private declarations } 
    FWnd: HWND; 
    FPaintRect: TRect; 
    FbkColor, FfgColor: TColor; 
    FInterval: integer; 
  protected 
    procedure Execute; override; 
  public 
    constructor Create(paintsurface : TWinControl; {Control to paint on } 
      paintrect : TRect;          { area for animation bar }
      bkColor, barcolor : TColor; { colors to use }
      interval : integer);        { wait in msecs between paints}
  end; 

implementation 

constructor TAnimationThread.Create(paintsurface : TWinControl; 
  paintrect : TRect; bkColor, barcolor : TColor; interval : integer); 
begin 
  inherited Create(True); 
  FWnd := paintsurface.Handle; 
  FPaintRect := paintrect; 
  FbkColor := bkColor; 
  FfgColor := barColor; 
  FInterval := interval; 
  FreeOnterminate := True; 
  Resume; 
end; { TAnimationThread.Create } 

procedure TAnimationThread.Execute; 
var 
  image : TBitmap; 
  DC : HDC; 
  left, right : integer; 
  increment : integer; 
  imagerect : TRect; 
  state : (incRight, incLeft, decLeft, decRight); 
begin 
  Image := TBitmap.Create; 
  try 
    with Image do  
    begin 
      Width := FPaintRect.Right - FPaintRect.Left; 
      Height := FPaintRect.Bottom - FPaintRect.Top; 
      imagerect := Rect(0, 0, Width, Height); 
    end; { with } 
    left := 0; 
    right := 0; 
    increment := imagerect.right div 50; 
    state := Low(State); 
    while not Terminated do  
    begin 
      with Image.Canvas do  
      begin 
        Brush.Color := FbkColor; 
        FillRect(imagerect); 
        case state of 
          incRight:  
          begin 
            Inc(right, increment); 
            if right > imagerect.right then  
            begin 
              right := imagerect.right; 
              Inc(state); 
            end; { if } 
          end; { case incRight } 
          incLeft:  
          begin 
            Inc(left, increment); 
            if left >= right then  
            begin 
              left := right; 
              Inc(state); 
            end; { if } 
          end; { case incLeft } 
          decLeft:  
          begin 
            Dec(left, increment); 
            if left <= 0 then  
            begin 
              left := 0; 
              Inc(state); 
            end; { if } 
          end; { case decLeft } 
          decRight:  
          begin 
            Dec(right, increment); 
            if right <= 0 then  
            begin 
              right := 0; 
              state := incRight; 
            end; { if } 
          end; { case decLeft } 
        end; { case } 
        Brush.Color := FfgColor; 
        FillRect(Rect(left, imagerect.top, right, imagerect.bottom)); 
      end; { with } 
      DC := GetDC(FWnd); 
      if DC <> 0 then 
        try 
          BitBlt(DC, 
            FPaintRect.Left, 
            FPaintRect.Top, 
            imagerect.right, 
            imagerect.bottom, 
            Image.Canvas.handle, 
            0, 0, 
            SRCCOPY); 
        finally 
          ReleaseDC(FWnd, DC); 
        end; 
      Sleep(FInterval); 
    end; { while } 
  finally 
    Image.Free; 
  end; 
  InvalidateRect(FWnd, nil, True); 
end; { TAnimationThread.Execute } 

end. 

//============================ HOW to USE IT ============================
{
 Usage: 
 Place a TPanel on a form, size it as appropriate.Create an instance of the 
 TanimationThread call like this: procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender : TObject); } 
var 
  ani : TAnimationThread; 
  r : TRect; 
begin
  r := Panel1.ClientRect;
  InflateRect(r, - Panel1.BevelWidth, - Panel1.BevelWidth);
  ani := TAnimationThread.Create(Panel1, r, Panel1.color, clBlue, 25);
  Button1.Enabled := False; 
  Application.ProcessMessages; 
  Sleep(30000);  // replace with query.Open or such 
  Button1.Enabled := True; 
  ani.Terminate; 
  ShowMessage('Done'); 
end.
```

Comment: Edited, it's the solution

Comment: -1, this code may be doing what you want, but it's not the answer to the question as asked (at least as far as I was able to understand the question).

Comment: The problem was in VCL mode. Because i don't see any result. Forever, it's my solution.

Comment: Calling `Application.ProcessMessages` is a very bad idea. Add the fact that you use multiple threads and is an invitation to disaster. Seems like you want to `WaitForSingleObject` with a timeout of 30 seconds instead.

Answer (score 5):

Mohammad, I think here is a classic example of **total** [multithreading] **misunderstanding**.

It is always good that you experiment with your code, but you must learn the basics.
As David said, you are breaking the rules. The whole concept. You might be a thousand times frustrated because you code does not work, but VCL will *not* suddenly become thread-safe because of your frustrations.

My suggestion would be to [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM). There is an excellent one.

A book by Martin Harvey, [Multithreading - The Delphi Way](http://thaddy.co.uk/threads/). The reading is easy and fun for real geeks. You may not want to go beyond mutexes, critical sections and concurrency control, but at least you will learn some really important concepts about the amazing world of multithreading.

Please do not expect anyone here at SO to answer the wrong questions. The most of the responders are professional and experienced programmers and they wouldn't wanna waste their time to dive into the discussions which are initially wrong. People here are quite boolean ;)

In other words, try to learn some very basic things before you post your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your code breaks VCL threading rules. All VCL access must be on the main thread.

If you want to show GUI in a different thread (and very seldom is that a good idea) you need to use raw Win32 API calls. And run a message loop in the thread.

I cannot tell you how to solve your problem because I don't know what your problem is. But if all you want to do is show a form before the main form, just do that. No obvious need for a thread.

Comment: Call CreateWindow. Very hard for us to suggest solutions without knowing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

it may be way too obvious but why dont you just run your code before the Form is created? 
(the others already suggested something like that)
if you create a new project and look at the source code of the project it will look like that:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.RES}

begin
  (* Insert your code in here so it runs before the mainform is created *) 

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Sorry, if i misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't my answer!

Comment: @Mohammadreza You asked why your code did not work. The answer is that you are breaking VCL threading rules. Please don't expect us to supply a solution to a problem that you did not state.

Comment: Well, my question is: I need a Thread that works independent, before `Form` be created. I want to do some codes in the `Thread`.

Comment: @Mohammadreza, it is not possible to create and run a VCL form in a thread.

Comment: Shouldn't you run the thread code **after** the `Application.Initialize` and **before** the `Application.CreateForm`?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question "*why is my thread run after form creation?*"
in `TCustomForm.Create`, `DoCreate` is called, which fires the `OnCreate` event.
At that point the form itself is already created and will be shown right after the `OnCreate` event returns.

In your case, you create the thread during this event.
Calling `Resume` only tells the thread that it can execute, but is does not guarantee immediate execution (plus it will have issues, as David explained). It is likely the `DoCreate` will finish before the `Execute` method is called.
This also means that `Synchronize` will not help, as that would be called from within the Execute context.

If you want to be certain that another form is first shown, you can do several things:

1. Make the other form your main form and show your current main form when it closes (or a button is clicked, a timer runs out, etc)
2. Put the code to display the other form in the `BeforeDestruction` method to have it execute before the constructor of the form. This will make it show first, but it will not prevent the main form from showing right after.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**QUESTIONS:**

(1) Is there a way to run my Thread out of main Form?

(2) I want to show a Form before the main Form begin to create ...

(3) ...while the main Form is shown.

**RESPONSES:**

(1) Yes. Do the creation of thread out of the Main form (not inside the Oncreate event of Main form).

(2) OK. (same responde of (1)). Do the form creation (or Thread) before create the Main form (not in OnCreate event of Main Form).

(3) **This is not possible with (1) and (2).**  Sorry.